# js.erb is called only on first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

in my rails 3 application, there is a **select_tag** with an **onchange** event, which sends an ajax request:

```
f.select 'forma_id', @collection, {:include_blank => true}, {:onchange => "goAjax('/lancamentos/receber_forma', this.value)", :class => 'btn'}
```

where, **goAjax** is:

```
function goAjax(_url, _value) {
  $.ajax({url: _url, data: 'value=' + _value, dataType: 'script'})
}
```

**lancamentos_controller#receber_forma** is (simplified version):

```
def receber_forma
  @lancamento = Lancamento.new(:forma_id => params[:value])
  logger.info 'forma_id = ' + @lancamento.forma_id
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :new }
    format.js
  end
end
```

and **receber_forma.js.erb**:

```
$('div#cartoes').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(label_tag(@lancamento.forma_id)) %>");
```

what is happening, is that when I choose a value on that select, the value rendered on the label is always the value sent on first call. The following value changes simply don't change the label text. The logger in the method receber_forma shows that the new selected value is always sent.

Someone knows what I'm doing wrong here??

p.s.:sorry any errors of English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely replacing your `div#cartoes` with a label, so the second time the code runs, it can't find a `div` with the `cartoes` id. You probably want to use `.html` instead of `.replaceWith`, so that the label becomes the content of the `div` rather than replacing it altogether:

```
$('div#cartoes').html("<%= escape_javascript(label_tag(@lancamento.forma_id)) %>");
```